# powercfg.exe not working properly

Tags: windows-8, power-management, powercfg

os:Windows 8 pro x64 build 9200 (fully updated)

I want to change the closing lid function through command line with powercfg.exe, so I gathered the required GUIDs and executed the following command:

```
C:\Users\wiki>powercfg /QUERY 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
  GUID Alias: SCHEME_MIN
  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936  (Lid close action)
      GUID Alias: LIDACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000001
```

as you can see nothing is wrong with the GUIDs; so I tried to change the functionality to `Do nothing` with these commands:

```
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 000
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 000
```

the commands executed successfully as in the picture (for active power plan):
[image]

but the problem is that the lid functionality is still the same as before (sleep), so I check the `Choose what closing the lid does`
[image]
and it is as if no changed happened!!!(as you can see in the picture below)
[image]

I got the query command of powercfg.exe and it says that it applied the first commands!!!

```
C:\Users\wiki>powercfg /QUERY 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936
Power Scheme GUID: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (High performance)
  GUID Alias: SCHEME_MIN
  Subgroup GUID: 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347  (Power buttons and lid)
    GUID Alias: SUB_BUTTONS
    Power Setting GUID: 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936  (Lid close action)
      GUID Alias: LIDACTION
      Possible Setting Index: 000
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Do nothing
      Possible Setting Index: 001
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Sleep
      Possible Setting Index: 002
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Hibernate
      Possible Setting Index: 003
      Possible Setting Friendly Name: Shut down
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000000
```

disabling/enabling the power plan-> no help

restarting the system->no help

Is there any extra settings I'm not aware of?!

Comment: Do you have the OEM power management software installed

Answer (score 0):

Activating hybrid sleep in the power plan worked for me

```
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e 1
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 000
powercfg /SETDCVALUEINDEX 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c 4f971e89-eebd-4455-a8de-9e59040e7347 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 000
```

This should activate hybridd sleep and then deactivates the suspension after closing the lid.